# Odd error message when trying to cast a structure in C++

Tags: c++, struct, casting, error-messaging

Using C++ on Linux, I just rather stupidly wrote this:

```
struct in_addr ip_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in)socket_addr).sin_addr;
```

Instead of the intended:

```
struct in_addr ip_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in*)&socket_addr)->sin_addr;
```

Giving me this error:

```
"error: no matching function for call to ‘sockaddr_in::sockaddr_in(sockaddr&)"
```

I know why I have the error (I was trying to cast a structure), but I don't understand why the error message says what it does. Can someone please explain?

Comment: `struct` is optional in C++. This looks like C where it is not.

Comment: I know `struct` is optional, but added it for clarity of the structures and marked it specifically as C++, just in case it was a C++-specific message.

Comment: @nwp: It's quite amusing (sort of) how often I see `struct sockaddr_in` and similar in C++, even production C++, presumably due to copy/paste learning from C tutorials! I've even accidentally done it myself once or twice.

Comment: Rest-assured, `struct` doesn't exist in my actual code. But I suppose I can only appreciate the pedantry ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the compiler encounters a C-style cast, [it tries to interpret it as one or two C++-style casts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), in the following order:

- `const_cast<new_type>(expression)`
- `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`
- `static_cast (with extensions)` followed by `const_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast<new_type>(expression)`
- `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`

The first choice that satisfies the requirements of the respective cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be compiled.

In your case, `static_cast<sockaddr_in>(socket_addr)` is selected. This is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), so the compiler looks for, and does not find, a constructor that takes a `const` reference to the object being cast.

Note that the same conversion does not trigger an error when applied to pointers, because language has built-in conversions between pointers of different types.

Answer (score 4):

When doing the cast on the type (and not the pointer), the compiler try to call the constructor of `sockaddr_in` that take a object of the same type as `socket_addr`. Since that constructor doesn't exists, the compiler throw the error you showed.

Comment: Note that this is not the only possible way such a conversion could happen. `socket_addr::operator sockaddr_in`could also exist.

Comment: Ah, thanks. when you say it's calling the constructor, is it the copy constructor?

Comment: The copy constructor takes only one argument of the same type (but is a reference) as the class.  In this case, this is a "normal" constructor that take one argument of the type of the casted value.

Comment: This makes sense when read in conjunction with @dasblinkenlight's answer

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how casts work — they convert an `A` to a `B`, and (unless `B` is a pointer or a reference) that requires invoking a conversion operator or a constructor. The compiler is trying to find a constructor to create a `sockaddr_in` from a `sockaddr`; none exists, hence the error.

It can't guess that you really meant to attempt a conversion to something else instead.

I've found that a large part of becoming a productive C++ programmer is learning the art of taking these compiler errors and using them to heuristically determine what the *actual* problem likely is. ;)